# Linq select list in list

Tags: c#, linq

my db returns a list of object3 which i want to transform to object1 with list of items(object2) (has same same properties which are in object3)

```
  List<object3> test()
        {
            var objectx = new object3
            {
                property1 = "x1",
                property2 = "x2",
                property3 = "x3",
                property4 = "x4"
            };
            var objectxx = new object3
            {
                property1 = "x1",
                property2 = "x2",
                property3 = "x3",
                property4 = "x4"
            };

            return new List<object3>() { objectx, objectxx };
        }

    }
    class object1 {
            public string property1 { get; set; }
        public string property2 { get; set; }
        public List<object2> Items { get; set; }
}

    class object2
    {
        public string property3 { get; set; }
        public string property4 { get; set; }
    }
    class object3
    {
        public string property1 { get; set; }
        public string property2 { get; set; }
        public string property3 { get; set; }
        public string property4 { get; set; }
    }
```

My code which doesn't work, output is 2 records of object1, but i want 1 record of object1 with 2 items.

```
var x = test().Select(x => new object1
            {
                property1 = x.property1,
                property2 = x.property2,
                
                Items = new List<object2> {

                        new object2
                        {
                            property3 = x.property3,
                            property4 = x.property4
                        }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the classes instead of describing them. It's important to provide a [repro] in a debugging question. Moreover, _"doesn't work"_ is not a good description of a problem. Do you get an error? Does it return a different result than you expect?

Comment: it seems that each entry of `object3` will create only 1 item in your list `public List<object2> items {get; set;}` why do you need a list? Actually your code looks correct. But we don't know what you expect and what you actually get. You need to tells us this stuff

Comment: "my code which doesn't work" how do you test that it doesn't work?

Comment: i want to have only 1record of object3 with List of objects 2

Comment: @SonDy The only problem that I can see with your code is that you used `Items` instead of `items` (I'm assuming that's just a typo in the question). Other than that, your code [works just fine](https://rextester.com/YVVA72649) and `output1` returns the same number of elements as the source list. Please try to provide a [repro] (i.e., one that can be copied and pasted) like I just did.

Comment: @SonDy what output do you expect?

Comment: " but i want 1 record of object1 with 2 items." where is the second item supposed to come from? what is the logic behind it? which values should the second items in the first record have for the porperties 3 & 4 ? Or do you want to reflect the amount of objects in the entire `test` list? so each `object1` element should have as much `object2` elements as there are in the source list `test` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tiny issue with the fact, that on the input side you have a flat structure with 4 properties, and on the output side you want a 2-tiered structure with 2 props on each layer. It just doesn't fit easily.

It basically means that you have to form things similar to 'object2' and then somehow mix&match them into groups called 'object1.items', at the same time, say, discarding duplicate property1+property2 pairs.

The code in your example is almost fine, but for each input item, it creates a new 'object1' item, and ends up with having a ton of 'object1' item, each having just a single 'object2'. There's no matching, there's no grouping.

Most probably, you want some kind of a `GroupBy` operation instead.

```
var output1 = _context.GetList<object3>(sql, parameters, CommandType.Text)
    .GroupBy(item => new{ item.property1, item.property2 })
    .Select(group =>
        new object1
        {
            property1 = group.Key.property1,
            property2 = group.Key.property2,
            items = group.Select(groupitem =>
                    new object2
                    {
                        property3 = groupitem.property3,
                        property4 = groupitem.property4,
                    }
                )
                .ToList()
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

Interesting things:

- note that the lambda in the GroupBy does not return `object1` - it could, but it would complicate the code with IComparers/EqualsOverride/etc - instead its lambda returns 2 properties in an anonymous object, that way, GroupBy can easily compare their contents and form the groups
- the 'Select' after `GroupBy` doesn't get `items` from the very source, but instead it gets `groups` formed by the GroupBy. A group is a list of items that had the same 'grouping key'=prop1+prop2, and that list also remembers that grouping key as `.Key` property. The key is what the GroupBy's lambda returned

small warning: code written from memory, never compiled, may contain small bugs and traces of milk and peanuts